# Android notification bar custom content not showing up

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

When setting my notification to a custom xml file with image buttons, those images don't show properly. Instead I just see a grey box (see below).

[image]

[image]

---

Here's my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

And here's my notification builder:

```
notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(activity, "TestNoficication")
    .setContentTitle("Test")
    .setContentText("test")
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launch_icon)
    .setOngoing(true)
    .setCustomContentView(new RemoteViews(activity.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification))
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
```

---

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Set those drawables as the `android:src`, not as the `app:srcCompat`. The system is what's actually inflating and displaying those `View`s, and it's not going to be looking for any attributes in your app's namespace, and it wouldn't handle support library attributes, anyway.

Comment: Okay. That worked. But will the images be displayed on older versions? My `minSdkVersion` is set to 17 and my `targetSdkVersion` is set to 28.

Comment: You're using system drawables. If they're actually present on a given device (which they should be, but possibly not on some odd manufacturers') then they will be usable in that device's version. You're technically "safer" using you're own drawables, and testing those on each version you support.

Comment: I see. So then if I want to use system default drawables, then using `app:srcCompat` won't work because they're being inflated by the system. That also means that the system will always grab the drawable no matter what the `SdkVersion` is with the exception of a few "odd" manufacturers. So then is this always the case when using any system default resource?

Comment: `app:srcCompat` just won't work at all. It doesn't matter where the drawables come from. I'm not really sure what you're asking, but I just meant that any resources that start with `android` are compiled into the platform, and are already on the device.

Comment: Okay. I understand what you meant. I was just confused because Android Studio made it so easy to link the android system drawables to my `ImageButton` that I thought that was the way it was supposed to be. I knew that `app:srcCompat` was meant to support vector drawables. But when Android Studio made it so easy, it lead me to believe that the android system drawables were in fact vector drawables.

Comment: I forgot to say that I made this xml using Android Studio's Layout Editor, and for `<ImageButton>`'s, `app:srcCompat` was the only option for linking a resource.

Comment: I'd imagine Android Studio just automatically suggested `app:srcCompat` because you're using the support libraries for older versions. I'm not sure of its exact behavior, though. I don't use the graphical layout editor.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. That didn't even occur to me. Well thank you for helping me understand something new about android development. I only just started developing for android three months ago, and I know I still have much to learn.

Comment: This ImageButton tag of .xml file is correct. If you have no any problem then you should use ImageView instead of ImageButton.